# SkewY with different values top and bottom

Tags: css, transform, css-shapes, skew

I would like to make a shape where the top is skewY -10deg and the bottom is 10deg to produce the shape as seen in the picture:

[image: div skewed bottom and top]

I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G9bXT/)**

This should do the trick:

CSS

```
#test {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
     background: black;
    position: relative;
}

#test:after, #test:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    color: transparent;
    width: 215px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    bottom: -20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(12deg);
}
#test:before {
    bottom: auto;
    top: -20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-12deg);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: After review it seems that maybe the CSS Perspective + Rotate would work nicely. But I can't seem to get content to not display distorted. http://jsfiddle.net/cyarema/G9bXT/3/

Comment: @ChristiYarema, do you want this http://jsfiddle.net/G9bXT/4/ ?

Comment: Gurpreet....VERY CLOSE. Thanks. Do you think the content could be contained w/within the red box? I tried an overflow hidden...didn't work. These people want images and text to be cut off by the red shape, not just ontop of it.

Comment: Very hard to understand what exactly you want. I might be able to help if you can upload desired result.

Comment: [link]http://www.partyplanetxtreme.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/ppx.png   This is the desired effect i'm trying to achieve without having to use graphics. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Though about this for a while but I can't find any decent CSS solution :(. I think you need to use image here.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gurpreet. These designers and their fancy sites...I think they try to give me a headache.